# Is there a plug-in to create a satin-like texture/light effect?

Tags: effect, texture

Is there a plug-in to add a satin-like texture to an image? I know how to play with canvas, porcelain, or rock surface like textures in Topaz Impression, which I use a lot, but I can't find anything for satin-like effect.

Is there anything out there to do that?

Sometimes I see this effect (a satiny kind of sheen) on photos of fields or road, but always wondered how it was achieved. I don't have a specific example to cite right now and did my best verbally describing what I want.

Comment: Could you post an example of this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?
[image]

What I did was searched for simply "satin" on Google, found a random image of a satin-like texture, and downloaded it. It doesn't matter what color it is. Once I imported it into Gimp, I converted it to greyscale with the Colorize effect (unless you still want the color, then don't do that step). Then I dragged in any old picture I happen to have lying around in my Downloads and placed the texture effect above it, like so:
[image]

Then I changed the blending mode to "overlay" on the texture layer. If you want it to be darker, you can change it do "multiply".

[image]